# Redis: how to efficiently check for empty nested key

Tags: python, redis, redis-py

I have a nested dictionary in my redis store and need to find all records where `key_2 == ""` then return value in `key_3`.  All `key_3` values will then be used to run mysql query to get `key_2` value and update the redis store.

```
[
  ...
  task_44903: {"key_1": 44903, "key_2": "", "key_3": 1}
  task_44229: {"key_1": 44229, "key_2": 4, "key_3": 2}
  ...
]
```

My current way of achieving this is

```py
    keys = r.keys(pattern='task_*')
    key_3 = set()
    for key in keys:
        values = r.get(key).decode('utf-8')
        values = ast.literal_eval(values)
        if values['key_2'] == '':
            key_3.add(values['key_3'])
```

Is there a more concise way of achieving this?

Comment: Did you consider using RedisJSON.io and move it to the Redis side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted.

```
data = [
  {'task_44903': {"key_1": 44903, "key_2": "", "key_3": 1}},
  {'task_44229': {"key_1": 44229, "key_2": "", "key_3": 1}},
  {'task_44230': {"key_1": 44229, "key_2": "", "key_3": 2}}
]

set([ v['key_3'] for item in data for _, v in item.items()  if v['key_2']==""])
```

Output

```
{1, 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify this to fit with your pipeline.

```
from itertools import chain


tasks = [
  {'task_44903': {"key_1": 44903, "key_2": "", "key_3": 1}},
  {'task_44229': {"key_1": 44229, "key_2": 4, "key_3": 2}}
]


def check_empty_key(tasks):
    # Your desired return value
    key_3s = set()

    # Makes a list of [{key_1:..., key_2:...}, {key_1:..., key_2:...}]
    task_details = chain.from_iterable(task.values() for task in tasks)
    # Iterate through each of these dictionaries
    for task_detail in task_details:
        # Will evaluate to True if task_detail['key_2'] is an empty string
        if not task_detail['key_2']:
            # Adds to the key_3s set
            key_3s.add(task_detail['key_3'])
            break
    else:
        # If no break statement was hit in the for loop, then raise this error
        raise ValueError('No empty key_2 in tasks')
    return key_3s
```

You could also do it like this:

```
def check_empty_key(tasks):
    key_3s = set()
    task_details = chain.from_iterable(task.values() for task in tasks)
    for task_detail in task_details:
        if not task_detail['key_2']:
            key_3s.add(task_detail['key_3'])
    return key_3s
```

But I like having the `else` so that I can raise an error when I need to add that into my control flow.